# View Permissions In Amazon REdshift - underlying table is recreated and permissions to view is blocked

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-redshift

I have a user in my Amazon Redshift that has access to a specific view. 
The underlying table behind this view recreated every day in the ETL process. When a day passes the view is recreated as well and because of that and the permission for this view is "blocked" to this specific user and I need to grant the permission again.

Here is the view Grant statements :

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA dwh TO monte_carlo_data_project;
GRANT SELECT ON dwh.v_dp_dim_account TO monte_carlo_data_project;
```

Here is a print screen that shows the view recreated : 
[image: DDL Tetx]

When the user tries to query the view again (after the view recreated) he is getting a permission error:

> SQL Error [500310] [42501]: Amazon Invalid operation: permission denied for relation v_dp_dim_account;

Only if I run the `GRANT SELECT` command again the user will get the permission again.

Any Idea of how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recreate your view once with `WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING`.

This will allow you to "decouple" the table from the view

From documentation

*WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING
Clause that specifies that the view is not bound to the underlying database objects, such as tables and user-defined functions. As a result, there is no dependency between the view and the objects it references. You can create a view even if the referenced objects don't exist. Because there is no dependency, you can drop or alter a referenced object without affecting the view*

For more info

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_VIEW.html

Comment: There are drawbacks to doing this you need to consider before implementing NO SCHEMA BINDING. Without schema binding in place it will be possible to alter the underlying table in a way that breaks the view, without any warnings or errors being generated until the view is next queried. Some tools will also not be able to see column information for views that don't have schema binding.

Comment: Understood , I took it into considiration - this is the best solution I can work with.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue recently, and the problem was slightly different.

I found that the user who CREATED the view also needed permissions to SELECT on the underlying tables